# Сайт отклоняет POST запрос. [PHP]

Tags: php, post, curl

Добрый день. Занялся написание API для чужого сайта (заказ). Но не могу отправить cURL POST. Есть такой код.

```
$cookie = send_post_get_cookie("https://www.interpals.net/app/auth/login");
if( $curl = curl_init() ) {

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.interpals.net/app/auth/login');
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
$headers = [
'X-Apple-Tz: 0',
'X-Apple-Store-Front: 143444,12',
'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Cache-Control: no-cache',
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
'Host: www.interpals.net',
'Referer: https://www.interpals.net/app/auth/login', //Your referrer address
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0',
'X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true'
];

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"username={$login}&password={$password}&csrf_token=$csrf_token");
$out = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
}
```

Все параметры скопировал с вкладки Network в Chrome. После отправки, сервер возвращает:

```
<body>
Redirecting to <a href="/">/</a>.
<script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"651b103a3b","applicationID":"17278031,27395599","transactionName":"MlNbN0FRWkVZAUALCwsZehZARFtbFyNBFgxfDFUMVFla","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":14,"atts":"HhRYQQlLSUs=","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","agent":""}</script></body>
</html>
```

А должен возвратить страницу ошибки, либо личный кабинет.

Прошу помощи. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Смотрите внимательно в браузере, что происходит при логине. Либо еще редирект происходит, либо выполняется какой-то JS код

Comment: До login есть еще один сценарий с wss://ws.interpals.net/socket/292/ny1pdxjg/websocket Что с ним делать?

Comment: Ну так смотрите, что этот сценарий делает. Мне отсюда не видно